# Where could I get A pig mask in GTA5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Such like this.[image]

I tried to find all the clothing store but found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You must go to the mask shop. Not the clothing shops. The mask shop is near the beach.

Answer (score 0):

You go to Mask shop down at Vespucci beach, near the skate park. When there you go under the Animal section under the mask shop menu, and scroll down until you see pig mask (costs $9,500).